# app crashing on loading thumbnails from media library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, media-library

i am integrating picture gallery in my windows phone 8 app.

here's the xaml code :

```
        <phone:LongListSelector Name="listdata" LayoutMode="Grid"
JumpListStyle="{StaticResource JumpListStyle}" GridCellSize="147,147">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Image Source="{Binding thumbnail}" Height="147" Width="147"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

        </phone:LongListSelector>

    </Grid>
```

and here's the imagemodel class :

```
public class imagemodel
{
    public WriteableBitmap thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Picture image;
    private Picture picture;

    public imagemodel(Picture pic)
    {
        image = pic;
        name = pic.Name;
        thumbnail = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(pic.GetThumbnail());

    }



}
```

MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();

```
    public void loadmygallery()
    {

        foreach (var picture in lib.Pictures)
        {

                imagemodel im = new imagemodel(picture);
                collection.Add(im);

        }

    }
```

the app crashes on opening the gallery page. This is possibly due to memory overload, if i limit thumbnails to be displayed to 30 or not a very high number, the code runs fine. Is there any way to still show all the thumbnails ??

Answer (score 0):

Since there's is little context and I can't see how the images are processed it's hard for me to tell you much about your error, but.... 
I think the thumbnails are not the cause if it DOES work fine when you limit the count. 
Try altering your code NOT to store images, typically programs cache thumbnails into a separate file or in worse cases into memory (only bad because images need to be processed fully every time) and display the thumbnails, so that your app doesn't store all your media library into ram.
The image itself is only read when it is opened.

Comment: see the edit to see how images are processed in the code

Comment: Could you limit the image count to 10 or 20 , load the app and check ram usage? Also let me know image sizes (in mb)